# Dividing table columns independently from other columns

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have a table where one of the columns is divided at a different position than the rest of the columns?

An example:

```
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
|   +---+---+
|   |   |   |
+---+   |   |
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Can you do this using colspan and rowspan? http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/tables/index_famsupp_30.html

Comment: @JoeKorolewicz, I wouldn't ask if I could. Can you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this via the `rowspan` property.

A table cell with rowspan will occupy the current row and that many rows below it.  You must remember to omit the corresponding table cells on subsequent rows.

http://jsfiddle.net/BmJaw/

Comment: +1, good answer. However, I like more td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 25px;
}
tr {
    height: 25px;
}

Comment: @vals those styles were just added to make the working HTML clear